# Preventive measures from mono-TeXLive coming poly-TeXLive 2017 system with this Vanilla + these PATHs?

Tags: installing, debian, texlive-2017

I installed the new TeXLive as instructed by the linked thread [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/13173) designed for older versions but should be accurate also for 2017. 
I have the following in my `$HOME/.bashrc` because instructions (+ David) after `tlmgr` successful installation say so to add them there. 
This thread answer [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/13173) proposes to run `tlmgr path add` after the successful installation, but no, do not do it if you have these PATHs - it will result only in errors. 
My `$HOME/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH    
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/info
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

However, I have noticed that over years my mono-TeXLive system becomes poly-TeXLive system because of various reasons, leading eventually to conflicts. 
So I am possibly doing something systematically wrong why `apt` starts to think that it needs to install second TeXLive in my system for `masi` and `sudo`. 
I would like to understand which measures there are to prevent it because they have been insufficient for me.

OS: Debian 8.7
TeXLive: 2017

Comment: no just adding it to the path will not be enough (we have an existing answer somewhere on how to install a stub texlive to keep the system package manager happy) but also you should not set the path in .bashrc as every time you start a nested new shell the path will be extended again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is that enough to tell the `apt` that there is already texlive? - - I noticed that I sometimes may run accidently `sudo apt install texlive*` which creates the poly-TeXLive system if no protections exist. I would like to prevent these mistakes because I have done them now a few times without noticing them.

Comment: the post that you link to has information about how to add stub packages for apt to cover texlive dependencies, this question is really just a duplicate of that isn't it?

Comment: I usually just add the equivs stuff explained on the TUG vanilla Debian page. And have not has issues with that. It is the equivs build package that tells apt that equivalents to the Debian packages have been installed and thus apt does not need to install those. Where exactly is that **tlmgr path add** mentioned? I would only use that on Windows